# how to make function run after other function finish

Tags: javascript

```
var showBoth = function(str, x) {
       showgrade(str, x);
       showsize(str, x);
     }
```

I have tried this:

```
var showBoth = function(str, x) {`enter code here`
        showgrade(str, x);
        setTimeout(function(){showsize(str, x)},500);
     }
```

but with `settime` out if the `showgrade` take too much time it will stop and run the `showsize`.

how to make `showsize` run when `showgrade` has finished running ?

this is my full function

```
 function showsize(str,x)
    {
        if (str=="")
          {
          document.getElementById("txtHintsize"+x+"").innerHTML="";
          return;
          } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("txtHintsize"+x+"").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","Function/ShowSize.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    function showgrade(str,x)
    {
        if (str=="")
          {
          document.getElementById("txtHintgrade"+x+"").innerHTML="";
          return;
          } 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("txtHintgrade"+x+"").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","Function/ShowGrade.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
     var showBoth = function(str, x) {
        showgrade(str, x);
        setTimeout(function(){showsize(str, x)},500);
     }
```

Comment: "how to make showsize run when showgrade has finished running" - that's what your first code snipped does.

Comment: What does `showgrade()` do? Is it an AJAX call? Does it use other asynchronous elements (timeouts, animations...)?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. In the question's title you ask `How to make a function run until another function finishes`, but in the question itself you ask `How to make a function run after another function has finished running`. Which is it you want?

Comment: It will show grade and size depend on product i choose and it has many values , that is the function of showsiZe and grade

Comment: @JohanesChan Could you please show us the implementations of `showgrade` and `showsize`?

Comment: I use code as i posted ,its only running 1 function

Comment: Sorry i used a wrong word the question is how to make a function run after other function finished

Comment: yes i will post my function

Answer (score 1):

Change your `showgrade` function's `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` like this

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("txtHintgrade" + x + "").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    showsize(str, x);
}
```

When the AJAX request returns back with response, it will invoke `onreadystatechange` function and that will mark the ending of the function. So, we simply invoke `showsize` from that function.

Comment: didnt work only showsize running

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var showBoth = function(str, x) {`enter code here`
    showgrade(str, x, function(){ showsize(str, x); });
 }
```

Then change your showgrade to look like this:

```
function showgrade(str, x, callback){
   //DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE
   callback.call();
}
```

Comment: If the `//DO WHAT YOU WANT HERE` is asynchronous, the callback will still be called before it's finished.

Comment: If its asynchronous you will need to wait till you get a response till make the callback.call();

Comment: sorry edited i know i am going to try it hope it'll work

Comment: it didnot work
its only one of them running

Comment: What do you mean? Here is the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/rYqHT/